# Why does my Program break after a few iterations?

Tags: python, string, search, crash, iteration

I am new to Python, so please don't kill me... I tried to write a simple Python program with which you can filter a list of words by letters. You enter a letter, tell the program if the letter is in the searched word and it filters the list bit by bit. But after entering 4 letters the program just breaks. No error is given, it just stops doing what it is supposed to do.

```
f = open("worte.txt", "r")
words = f.read().split()
f.close()
print("list contains %i words" % len(words))
words = [word.upper() for word in words]

lengthword = int(input("How long is the word?"))
correctlength = []
correctletter = []

for i in words:
    if len(i) == lengthword:
        correctlength.append(i)
print("list contains %i words" % len(correctlength))

while True:
    userinput = input("Enter a letter").upper()
    inputcorrect = input("Is this letter correct? (Y/N)").upper()
    if inputcorrect == "Y":
        for word in correctlength:
            for letter in word:
                if userinput == letter:
                    correctletter.append(word)
                    break
        correctlength = correctletter
        correctletter = []
        print(len(correctlength))
        print(correctlength)
    elif inputcorrect == "N":
        for word in correctlength:
            for letter in word:
                if userinput not in letter:
                    correctletter.append(word)
                    continue
                else:
                    break
        correctlength = correctletter
        print(len(correctlength))
        print(correctlength)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Working fine. Entered 30 letters and still running.

Comment: Seriously? Now I am even more baffled